# POSIX or Linux API function to get file extension from path

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I need a POSIX or Linux API function that takes file path and returns this file's extension. Every platform should have one, but I can't it for Linux. What's it called?

Comment: File extensions have little meaning in the unix world

Comment: Wouldn't a more portable solution with `boost::filesystem` be preferable?

Comment: @juanchopanza: it might be if I used boost already, but I won't include it for just this function. On Windows I have WinAPI function and on Mac I have Cocoa function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use `strrchr` to find the last `'.'` in the pathname. If it doesn't exist, there's no "extension".

Next, use `strchr` to check whether there's any `'/'` after the last `'.'`. If so, the last `'.'` is in a directory component, not the filename, so there's no extension.

Otherwise, you found the extension. You can use the pointer to the position one past the `'.'` directly as a C string. No need to copy it to new storage unless the original string will be freed or clobbered before you use it.

Note: The above is assuming you define "extension" as only the final `'.'`-delimited component. If you want to consider things like `.tar.gz` and `.cpp.bak` as extensions, a slightly different approach works:

First, use `strrchr` to find the final `'/'`. If not found, treat the start of the string as your result.

Second, use `strchr` to find the first `'.'` starting from the position you just found. The result is your extension.

Comment: -1 because `std::string::find` exists. No need to use potentially unsafe C-style functions in C++.

Comment: There is nothing "unsafe" about any function that's being used in a read-only manner. Also, OP tagged this question both C and C++, so an answer that works in either language is the only appropriate one.

Comment: missed the `C` tag. Removed the downvote. Still, this doesn't work if the user wants to get multiple extensions (in the case of `.cpp.bak`) and the file name starts with a `.`. Also, if the user is using C++, it's un-idiomatic to use C-style functions.

Comment: OK, I added an alternate version for your definition of extension.

Comment: @R..: fair point, `C` tag removed. And thanks for pointing out that my question title is poorly stated.

Comment: OK. I'll leave the answer as-is since I'm not familiar with best-practices for how to do this in C++, but I hope there's an analogous in-place way to do it without copying the string around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a default function for this.

In my filesystem library, I just apply string operations.

First, I get the filename with extension from the full path, looking for `/` separators and extracting everything after the last one. Then, I grab everything after the first `.` dot character, including the dot itself. It worked well so far.

Remember that some system files can start with a `.` dot character - so check if the filename begins with the dot character before extracting the extension.

---

**Algorithm**

1. Get file name from full path by removing folder names from the left:

   - `/home/test/.myfile.cpp.bak` ->
   - `/test/.myfile.cpp.bak` ->
   - `/.myfile.cpp.bak` ->
   - `.myfile.cpp.bak`
2. Check if the file name begins with `.`:

   - If it does, remove it from current file name `.myfile.cpp.bak` -> `myfile.cpp.bak`
3. Now, extract everything after the first `.` you encounter from the left (if you want multiple extensions) - otherwise, extract everything after the last `.` from the left

   - `myfile.cpp.bak` -> `.cpp.bak` (first case)
   - `myfile.cpp.bak` -> `.bak` (second case)

Comment: And if it's a system file starting with dot? Sure, I can do it manually and it will work in _most_ cases. But not all.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I have a special case for that

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: added an example of how the algorithm could work.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo `myfile.cpp.bak` is not a `.cpp.bak` file, just a `.bak` (that's how most operating systems handle it, if they care about extensions at all that is). You should just extract the end of the string *after* the last `.`

Comment: This is seriously overcomplicated.

Comment: See my answer for a simpler approach.

Comment: @R..: maybe it is for the task Violet Giraffe is trying to accomplish, but it is easy to divide in different functions. I do it this way because, in my filesystem library, I may only need the file name, or I may need the extensions, or both file name and extensions. It is an extensible solution, that's what I mean.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: "Find the extension" does not require separating the directory and filename components. Those are completely separate operations that should not come into play when what you want is the extension.

Comment: @R..: it is required in case the user wants to get `.cpp.bak` and not only `.bak` and the file name starts with a `.`

Comment: If you want to use that definition of "extension" (note: "extension" is not defined in any standard way) you can just `strrchr` to find the last `'/'` first, then search for the first `'.'`. There is absolutely no sense in making multiple temporary strings, which is both inefficient and (much worse) subject to the possibility of failure, which correct code has to check for, and which makes your code much more complex and error-prone.

Comment: R..: good point. If all the user wants to do is get the extension of a file, your answer is the more appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Including boost for filesystem is a bit too much. But as boost implementation reach TR2 and is implemented in visual studio it's maybe time to start looking at it.
http://cpprocks.com/introduction-to-tr2-filesystem-library-in-vs2012/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx

Comment: yes I read it. if EVEN Microsoft do the TR2 implementation of filesystem it's almost sure that the implementation will reach standardisation. So we could use it today and have an already  portable way, maybe standard, to deal with files and paths.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me the best way to solve this problem (in absence of API function, which itself is weird) is to combine Vittorio's and R.'s answers with `basename` function that takes a path and returns the file name, if the path points to a file: http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename

I also convert the resulting string to UTF-16 with `mbstowcs` and do all the finding with `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring fileExtFromPath (const char * path)
{
   const char * fileName = basename(filePath);
   wchar_t buffer [MAX_PATH] = {0}; // Use mblen if you don't like MAX_PATH
   const std::wstring fileNameW (buffer);
   const size_t pointPosition = fileNameW.rfind(L".");
   const std::wstring fileExtW = pointPosition == 0 ? std::wstring() : fileNameW.substr( + 1);
   return fileExtW;
}
```