# What is the extension of "/whatever/foo."

Tags: file, unix, naming-conventions, filenames

### Input

`/whatever/foo.`

### Problem

Extract the extension.

### Output

- `""` -- empty string?
- `null` -- no extension?

### Thoughts

For sure the **basename** is `foo.`. The equivalent question is: what is the **stem** here? Depending on the answer, we have different conclusions:

- stem is `foo` --> extension is an empty string
- stem is `foo.` --> there is no extension

Is there any... tool or system that is widely used and would define the behavior in such scenarios? A UNIX program maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of "extension" in UNIX.

You might deduce it by the fact that POSIX does not include any such concept in its [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html).

See also Wikipedia's [Filename_extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) and [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) (especially the final section).

This question is related: [POSIX or Linux API function to get file extension from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466716/posix-or-linux-api-function-to-get-file-extension-from-path) .